# Inform WPF of expected type for object property on viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Suppose I have a viewmodel that exposes a 2-way bindable property `P` of type `object`. But suppose also that I really do expect a single concrete type, but I don't know what that will be until runtime. Is there any way I can inform WPF, e.g. through a second property, of the expected type for `P` so the framework can do its own built-in type conversions when `P` is set as a result of some UI action (`TextBox` input)? I would prefer to do this on the VM side rather than in XAML so the VM consumer doesn't need to be aware that anything unusual is going on.

Here's an example that illustrates a way this might happen:

```
class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   private readonly object _obj;
   private readonly PropertyInfo _prop;

  public ViewModel(object obj, PropertyInfo prop)
  {
     _obj = obj;
     _prop = prop;
  }

  public object P
  {
    get { /* return value of _prop on _obj */ }

    set { /* set _prop on _obj to value,
             but I have to convert from string manually */ }
  }

  public Type ExpectedType => _prop.PropertyType;
}
```

Is there (for example) any kind of attribute I can set on `ExpectedType`, or a magic name I can use for it, that will tell WPF that it is returning the type I expect for `P`?

Comment: Can't you just Bind to the Property and for visualization purpose use a datatemplateselector? Or is this too specific in you scenario?

Comment: Btw, the wpf chat room is an excellent place to ask things like this -- if either you or @KroaX ever need to run ideas past a larger group, interactively...

Comment: What are you storing in `P`? Is it a boxed value?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Yes, in my particular case, that is virtually certain

Comment: If it's boxed, I'd expect that the binding engine will successfully unbox the value, and inherently use the strongly-typed value.You might be surprised to find out that this just all magically works. Have you tried it? (just binding to the object property?) If so, specially, what didn't do what you expected?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling The problem is that, in the case of `TextBox` input, `P`'s setter gets type `string`, and then it's up to me to convert it to `ExpectedType`. I can do that, but I suspect the WPF engine would do it better.

Comment: I think you could create a generic view-model class and instantiate it at runtime using reflection to obtain a constructor with a proper type parameter.

Comment: Can't you write your own `IValueConverter` ?

Comment: @Tseng I *could*, and I could also do the conversion in `P`'s setter, but I'd rather let WPF do it since its conversion code is much more mature and tested than anything I would write.

Comment: @Grx70 That's an intriguing idea; I'll have to give it a try...